# laptop Keyboard typing input output mismatch

Tags: windows-7, keyboard

Suddenly my laptop (Acer Aspire 7740) (windows7) keyboard is malfunctioning. The output does not match the actual input i type.

When I type:
A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z ` 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 - = [ ] \ ; ' , . /

i get the output 
A B DC DC DC GF GF HN M, J M, . €M, HN . €P Q GF SX T U V SX SX HN Z a 1 sx 3 dc gf  hn   / - / ] / \; ' m, .€ / \;

Even enter and backspace \; give me the following outputs:
\; \;

Left arrow functions as the tab button.

Use of a external keyboard gives me the correct output so I am not able to understand what is the problem. I tried cleaning the keyboard and pressing fn+numlock or fn+shift+numlock. This also did not solve the problem.

Thanks for any help you can give.

In response to the comments and answers uptil now:

The problem started after probably 5 hours of inactivity. Do not find any spillage. None of the keys are stuck and feel normal / move freely. Multiple keyboards are not enabled so I dont think that is the problem too. Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: How sudden? In the middle of use, or after a period of inactivity?

Comment: Did you spill something (especially a carbonated beverage) on the keyboard?  If so, it's probably toast.  Otherwise, look for a key that's stuck -- operate all keys a couple dozen times, and make sure they all "feel" the same.

Comment: (I assume you tried powering completely off and rebooting.)

Comment: The problem started after probably 5 hours of inactivity. Do not find any spillage. None of the keys are stuck and feel normal / move freely. Multiple keyboards are not enabled so I dont think that is the problem too.

Answer (score 2):

A possibility is that you have defined multiple keyboard layouts and have accidentally switched by pressing `<CTRL>` and `<SHIFT>` together.

Comment: You are right for my case.